# Lazarus: typecast overload for generics

Tags: operator-overloading, lazarus, freepascal

I try to build a generic class (f.e. a Set- Class). This class should have a function "AsString". But in it i need to typecast  to string.
How to declare this typecast?

Short Code:

```
  generic TSet<_T> = class
  private
    FList: array of _T;
  public
    function AsString:string;
  end;

  TSetDouble = specialize TSet<double>;  

function TSet.AsString: string;
var i:integer;
begin
  result := '';
  for i := 0 to Length(FList) - 1 do
    result := result + IntToStr(i) + ' ' + string (FList[i]) + #13#10;
end;
```

I need a way to typecast FList[i] to string for every "known" special type (of course: each type needs its own operator overloading).
something like

```
operator string(const X:integer):string;
begin result := IntToStr(x);end;

operator string(const X:TMyRecord):string;
begin result := IntToStr(MyRecord.Number) + MyRecord.Text;end;
```

Any Idea?

Comment: You say, "every special type", but your class is generic. It can accept any type. Records, classes, strings, enumerated types, floating point types, interfaces, etc. Some of these simply don't have converstions to string.

Comment: Exactly that is the reason for my question. I look for a way to define typecast from mytype to string for every type I want to deliver to my generic class. I know it is possible in python and as far as I remember it was possible in C++, but is it possible in Lazarus/FreePascal? Is there another way to do this? (of course I can create my class w/o the function "AsString", but it is useful, so I want to do it)

Comment: I don't think such a thing really exists. There are bigger problems with your design. Not all types have a meaningful equals operator. How do you compare two records for equality? Remember that a set cannot have duplicates, unlike the array that you use to implement this. I'm not convinced you've thought through all the implications of allowing arbitrary types.

Comment: I removed the operator overloading tag. The question isn't about operator overloading. It's about generics. They are not the same thing.

Comment: I do not agree. I want to overload the typecast Operator. If you add an integer to a float the integer is typecasted implicit by an Operator. Exactly that I want to overload (for string, I hope it exists). The same question could be written w/o generics, generics are only to illustrate the reason.

Comment: No. Overloading works for a finite number of specific types that you define. Your code is generic and needs to work for any type. You won't get anywhere with overloading. You are asking for a generic solution. I made this point in my first comment. I don't think you understand at all yet what it means to be generic. Until you can grasp that fully we will be going round and round in circles.

Comment: and if there is a way to overload the typecast- Operator (if exists), I surely can overload the equal- Operator, isn't it? Since I lost my Delphi I love my Lazarus, I do not want to stick to Java, C* or python. And so I look for solving my Problems.

Comment: As I said, no amount of overloading helps with generics.

Comment: Ok, maybe you are right. I think I could no explain, what I Need. But: How to define an overloading of f.e. an equal- Operator for let me say a record? So that I can write if (MyRec = YourRec) then ...?

Comment: I don't think you can realistically expect to do that for an arbitrary type. I don't see that what you are attempting, in its current generality, is realistic.

Comment: I am happy that you think for me ;) But can you tell me, how to overload an equal- Operator for a Special record? (not generic, not Abstract, only simple: a record with f.e. ZIP code and City Name, so that I can write IF (myCity = YourCity) THEN ... instead of IF (myCity.ZIP = yourCity.ZIP) AND (myCity.Name=yourCity.Name) THEN ...?

Comment: That's a different question, and won't help you at all with your generic class. I'd look in the documentation to understand operator overloading: https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refch15.html

Comment: Actually you are almost here. Just change `operator string(const X:TMyRecord):string;` to `operator explicit(const X:TMyRecord):string;` You also can to use [`WriteStr` procedure](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/writestr.html) to convert all simple types (numbers, strings, booleans and enumerations) to string using same code.

Comment: @Abelisto Won't help with generics

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "_The same question could be written w/o generics, generics are only to illustrate the reason._" in the fifth comment. Why do you think that we are still talking about generics? Surely, in the Pascal it is no any common way to convert **anything** to string, but as I understood from the question and comments it is even not necessary.

Comment: @Abelisto OK, so you agree that operator overloading won't help solve the problem asked in the question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because you did not asked the right question: "Do you need it for **any** type or just for limited number of specific types?" at the beginning but initiate the long discussion, we are still not sure what exactly was asked.

Comment: @Abelisto The question is about generics. So it is needed for arbitrary types, or it won't compile. Probably the best toy can do is some RTTI based type sniffing but overloading won't help. And I don't think fpc has strong RTTI anyway so that won't work out.

Comment: I am sorry, my English seems to be too bad to express, what I need. Be free to clearify this. When I went home yesterday I thought over the misunderstanding. I do not need help for generics, but for operator overloading. The misunderstanding could be the following: Of course, I know that it is impossible to write only one overloading for all types, I would need an overloading for each type I want to use with my generic type. I am new to generics and lazarus overloading, but I  know templates and operator overloading in MVC++ 6, so I am not totally new to this matter. (I program for 30 years)

Comment: @Abelisto: operator explicit (const X : integer) : string; begin result := inttostr(X);end;
works fine and as expected. Thank you very much. And can you tell me, how to overload the "="- operator? (Any link to a dokumentation would be great too)

Comment: So then you need to remove this question probably, and start again. Because this question asks about generics. Which are not the same as templates. You could do it the way you imagine using C++ templates and operator overloading, but that will not work for generics. Try for yourself. Try using the `=` comparison operator in a method of your generic set class. It won't compile because the compiler cannot guarantee that all specialisations support `=`. With C++ templates this check would be applied at the time of specialisation. That's the point I made in my very first comment.

Comment: And why are you asking for links to the documentation? I already linked the documentation for fpc operator overloading? Are you reading these comments?

Comment: @David Heffernan: In my question the only "Question" is "How to declare this typecast?" You interpreted it as generic question. It was started as operator overloading question as I told you from the beginning. And sorry for the question for documentation. I overread this, thank you for the link (now I found). I am sorry for misunderstanding and thank you for ALL.

Comment: I'm sorry but you are wrong. The post has generics in the subject and the code declares a generic type. You can't use any operators of generic type `_T` in a method of `TSet<_T>`. You could if you were working with C++ templates, but not with generics. Try it and see for yourself. Try using the `=` operator. If you want to ask about operator overloading, ask about that, but don't mix generics in there because they are not compatible. But read the documentation first, you won't need further clarification after that I am sure.

Comment: I tried it out and it worked fine. I will answer myself and you can try it out.

Comment: Well, I stand corrected. These are not generics in the way that term is usually used, in Java, C#, Delphi. These are templates. And of course in that case everything I have said is total nonsense. Sorry. This is all caused by my not realising that this fpc construct is akin to templates rather than generics.

Comment: no problem, anything helped, and if only to make things clear. I left Delphi before generics, can you point out the differences between generics and templates (or a link to a documentation)?

Comment: I'd do some web search. Concentrate on C# generics vs C++ templates. Generics are really quite limited in many ways. Inability to use basic operators is often crippling.

Comment: Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to David Heffernan and Abelisto.
Maybe I did not explain the problem as good as possible, but I got the answers I needed. You see the code of an generic Set- class with 3 specializations: integer, double, TestRecord. I shortened it as much as I could.

It works fine (combination operator overloading and generics).
Hope, it helps anyone more than only me.

unit uSet;

```
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

type

  TTestRecord = record
    i:integer;
    t:string;
    x:double;
  end;

  { TSet }

  generic TSet<_T> = class
  private
    FList: array of _T;
    function GetCount: integer;
    function GetItem(const pcnIndex: integer): _T;
    procedure SetItem(const pcnIndex: integer; const pcItem: _T);
  public
    function FindElement(lvI: _T):integer;
    procedure AddItem(lvI: _T);
    procedure DelItem(lvI: _T);
    property Count:integer read GetCount;
    property Item[const pcnIndex:integer]:_T read GetItem write SetItem;default;
    function IsElement(lvI: _T):boolean;
    function AsString:string;
    constructor Create;
    Destructor Destroy;override;
  end;

  TSetString = specialize TSet<string>;
  TSetDouble = specialize TSet<integer>;
  TSetTestRecord = specialize TSet<TTestRecord>;

implementation

//this operator is needed in function FindElement
operator = (const pcR1, pcR2 : TTestRecord) : boolean;begin result := (pcR1.i=pcR2.i) and (pcR1.t=pcR2.t) and (pcR1.x=pcR2.x); end;

//this operator is needed in function AsString
operator explicit (const pcR1 : TTestRecord) : string;begin result := pcR1.t;end;
operator explicit (const X : integer) : string; begin result := inttostr(X);end;
operator explicit (const d : double) : string;begin result := FloatToStr(d) ;end;

{ TSet }

function TSet.GetCount: integer;
begin
  result := length(FList);
end;

function TSet.GetItem(const pcnIndex: integer): _T;
begin
  if (0 <= pcnIndex) and (pcnIndex < length(FList)) then
    result := FList[pcnIndex]
  else
    raise Exception.Create(Format('Index nicht im gültigen Bereich (0<=%d<%d)',[pcnIndex, length(FList)]));
end;

procedure TSet.SetItem(const pcnIndex: integer; const pcItem: _T);
begin
  if (0 <= pcnIndex) and (pcnIndex < length(FList)) then
    FList[pcnIndex] := pcItem
  else
    raise Exception.Create(Format('Index nicht im gültigen Bereich (0<=%d<%d)',[pcnIndex, length(FList)]));
end;

function TSet.FindElement(lvI: _T): integer;
var i:integer;
begin
  result := -1;
  for i := 0 to length(FList) - 1 do
    if lvI = FList[i] then begin
      result := i;
      break;
    end;
end;

procedure TSet.AddItem(lvI: _T);
begin
  if FindElement(lvI) = -1 then begin
    SetLength(FList,length(FList)+1);
    FList[length(FList)-1] := lvI;
  end;
end;

procedure TSet.DelItem(lvI: _T);
var i, lvnIndex:integer;
begin
  lvnIndex := FindElement(lvI);
  if  lvnIndex > -1 then begin
    for i:=lvnIndex to Length(FList)-2 do
      FList[i]:=FList[i+1];
    SetLength(FList,length(FList)-1);
  end;
end;

function TSet.IsElement(lvI: _T): boolean;
begin
  result := FindElement(lvI) > -1;
end;

function TSet.AsString: string;
var i:integer;
begin
  result := '';
  for i := 0 to Length(FList) - 1 do
    result := result + IntToStr(i) + ' ' + string(FList[i]) + #13#10;
end;

constructor TSet.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  SetLength(FList,0);
end;

destructor TSet.Destroy;
begin
  SetLength(FList,0);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

end.
```

This is not perfect at all, it only shall show the answer to the question: How can I operator overloading if I want develop generic classes. Any hints to improvement are very welcome.